OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol on Pycharm using scapy
I am trying to learn more coding to sniff network traffic and I chose to learn about the python package scapy. Tutorials are going OK except whenever I try to send packets I get an error stating "OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol". Here is a simple terminal history to show what I am getting:
Python IDE in py charm terminal
>>> p = IP(dst="github.com")/ICMP()
>>> r = sr1(p)

Error report
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/wilkins/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 663, in sr1
ans, _ = sr(*args, **kargs)

File "/home/wilkins/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 650, in sr
s = conf.L3socket(promisc=promisc, filter=filter,

File "/home/wilkins/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 484, in __init__
self.ins = socket.socket(

File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
_socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)

OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

I have looked online for this error and I cannot find any answers to my situation. My network settings are fine. Not sure why I cannot send any packets through scapy. I am using pycharm community edition. My OS is Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 4.4.8
When I send the sr(...) command, I expect the packet to send and receive and answer. I have played a little with my network settings but don't want to mess with it too much.
